# Nash Equilibrium for this sequential game

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Player one (P1) picks a number between 100 and 0 inclusive. Let's call this number X. Whatever the X P1 has picked, it is subtracted from 100 and now is in front of P1. So P1 has 100 - X in front of him. This X amount is then delivered to P2. Then P2 picks a Y amount between X and 0 inclusive. That Y amount is deducted from P2, multiplied by 3 and added to whatever was in front of P1.

So at the end, P1 ends up with 100-X+3*Y and P2 ends up with X-Y. What is the Nash Equilibrium for this game?

Answer (score 1):

No matter what strategy player one picks (no matter which $x$ is chosen) it is always in the best interest of player two to pick $y=0$. Given that player one knows that player two will always pick $y=0$, the best strategy for player one is to pick $x=0$.

The notion of equilibrium you want to use in this kind of extended form game is called [subgame perfect equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgame_perfect_equilibrium), and it is most easily solved via backwards induction. The linked article covers some small examples of this.

Comment: Thank you. It was my thought also but since I'm pretty new to the topic I wanted to make sure.